# How to show max or value on bar chart top with pd.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to show the value of the bar chart on the top of the bar chart. I using DataFrame for that.
This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
data = {
    'L': [86.0, 91.7, 92.3, 92.8],
    'D': [87.6, 90.5, 91.1, 91.1], 
    'K': [87.0, 91.5, 92.5, 92.0],
    'N': [84.0, 84.9, 91.7, 89.9],
    'S': [91.0, 87.0, 88.8, 91.0]   
   }
barWidth = 0.9
colours = {"L": "#837E7C", "D": "#98F99F", "K": "#FFE24A", "N": "#E8ADAA", "S": "#87C0FF" }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['L','D', 'K', 'N', 'S'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],)
df.plot.barh(figsize=(4,8), color=colours, fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Type', fontsize = 14)
plt.yticks(rotation=90, ha="center", rotation_mode='anchor')
plt.label('Result', fontsize = 14)
plt.show()
```

and out is:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

But did not show value on top. How to do it, using my code.

Comment: See this: [https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html)

Comment: I need to set it in dataframe plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following what you want? You need a workaround to iterate  your multibar chart. The first step is to define an `ax` object. The second step is to use a `for` loop to get the values of each
bar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal
data = {
    'L': [86.0, 91.7, 92.3, 92.8],
    'D': [87.6, 90.5, 91.1, 91.1], 
    'K': [87.0, 91.5, 92.5, 92.0],
    'N': [84.0, 84.9, 91.7, 89.9],
    'S': [91.0, 87.0, 88.8, 91.0]   
   }
barWidth = 0.9
colours = {"L": "#837E7C", "D": "#98F99F", "K": "#FFE24A", "N": "#E8ADAA", "S": "#87C0FF" }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['L','D', 'K', 'N', 'S'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
ax = df.plot.barh(figsize=(4,8), color=colours, fontsize = 14)
for p in ax.patches:  
  ax.annotate(str(p.get_width()), (p.get_x() + p.get_width(), p.get_y()), xytext=(1, 2), textcoords='offset points')


plt.ylabel('Type', fontsize = 14)
plt.yticks(rotation=90, ha="center", rotation_mode='anchor')

plt.show()
```

[image]